# Fluid layout: full width not applied in container with undefined size

Tags: layout, vaadin

I'm having trouble creating a fluid layout with Vaadin. As I understand it, in order for a container's size to be calculated based on its contents, I have to use the `setSizeUndefined()` method.
This works fine, but an issue arises when I want to add components wich take up all the available space to this container with undefined size. I cannot get this to work.

Here's a simplified sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
layout.setSizeUndefined();
layout.setMargin(false);

layout.addComponent(createButton("A somewhat longer label"));
layout.addComponent(createButton("Short label"));

private Button createButton(String label) {
    Button button = new Button(label);
    button.setSizeFull();
    button.setWidth("100%");
    return button;
}
```

The buttons do not take up the entire width of the vertical layout container. I have read here and there that one is not allowed to set "100%" sizes inside containers with undefined size, but then how am I supposed to achieve what I want to achieve bearing in mind that I need that undefined size for my fluid layout?
In case someone thinks the undefined size is not necessary for my use case, I'll be happy to provide more information on that. I have a strong [Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) background which may cause met to look at this problem from the wrong angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you cannot use relatively sized components within a VerticalLayout that has an undefined size. The functionality you are looking for exists in an add-on called [WeeLayout](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/weelayout).

Comment: So I have to use a plugin - and a BETA version at that - to achieve such basic functionality? My initial love for Vaadin is slowly fading :(

Comment: Using add-ons are more than normal, they are the thing that makes Vaadin great. I can tell you that the author of WeeLayouts is the same person that has been working on the core layouts, so he knows what he is doing.